# How to Write Regex to match third array element

Tags: jquery, regex

I need help to write a regex that helps me to match the third array key.

For example
Array name : `soundConfig[0][songs][1][html]`
regex to match first key element `[0] => /\[(\d+)\]/`

I want to match the third array element `[1]`

Thanks in advance,

Comment: And why exactly would you even *try* to do that? Just parse it and get the values within the language.

Comment: I understand, but I have a dynamic Form that adds all elements dynamically, so to get post proper values, I need to replace that key, and it's only the way regex can do it easily...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the third value, you could also use a capture group and use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to match from `[` till `]`

In the replacement use group 1 `$1` followed by the replacement.

```
^(\w+(?:\[[^\][]*]){2}\[)[^\][]*(?=])
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1** (Referred to by `$1` in the replacement code)

  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
  - `(?:\[[^\][]*]){2}` Repeat 2 times matching `[`...`]`
  - `\[` Match the opening `[` for the third part
- `)` Close group 1
- `[^\][]*` Match till the closing `]` (which is the part you want to replace)
- `(?=])` Positive lookahead, assert the closing `]` for the third part at the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QhoKkO/1)

```js
const regex = /^(\w+(?:\[[^\][]*]){2}\[)[^\][]*(?=])/;
const str = `soundConfig[0][songs][1][html]`;
console.log(str.replace(regex, `$1REPLACEMENT`));
```

Or if the first and the third part have to be a digit and according to the comment you want to increment the value, you can use 2 capture groups.

```
^(\w+\[\d+]\[\w+]\[)(\d+)(?=])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/25xaJu/1)

```js
const regex = /^^(\w+\[\d+]\[\w+]\[)(\d+)(?=])/;
const str = `soundConfig[0][songs][1][html]`;
console.log(str.replace(regex, (_, g1, g2) => `${g1}${++g2}`));
```

Comment: Can you please revise the snippet that increments value instead of replacing it with REPLACEMENT?

Comment: @PrashantRawal I have updated the second example to increment the value of capture group 2.

Answer (score 0):

Using `match()` with the pattern `\[.*?\]` we can try:

```js
var input = "soundConfig[0][songs][1][html]";
var parts = input.match(/\[.*?\]/g);
console.log(parts[2]);
```

If instead your goal is to *replace* the third array index with something else, then use string split followed by a join:

```js
var input = "soundConfig[0][songs][1][html]";
var parts = input.split(/(?=\[)/);
var output = parts.slice(0, 3).join("") + "[NEW]" + parts.slice(4, 5).join("");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: $this.attr('name', $this.attr('name').replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function($0, $1) { return '[' + (+$1 + 1) + ']'; })); so regex match third element [1] and increment [2]...right now it match first element [0]

Comment: I don't understand your comment.